# creating a jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

Hi I'm hoping to create a accordion with jquery out of 3 divs:

basically I've got three instances of this div

```
<div id="formcont">
        <h3>Add New Blog Posts :</h3>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <table width="457" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="131">Blog Title:</td>
              <td width="145"><label for="textfield"></label>
              <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Blog Content:</td>
              <td><textarea name="textfield2" cols="50" rows="12" id="textfield2">    </textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>

        </div>
```

And I'd like the h3 to be the button and the form to be the content . ALso if someones got the time could they give a brief explanation on how the code works .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: you can refer this link also for your task, [http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/accordian-menu/](http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/accordian-menu/) this may be helpful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Demo](http://net.tutsplus.com/demos/020_jQueryUI/accordion-custom-jquery.php)

As per the demo :

add `heading` class to your h1 tag and wrap your code in `<ul id="accordion">` like this :

```
<ul id="accordion">
  <li>Your Heading and form come here </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the [jQuery accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/). It works with nested lists, definition lists, or just nested divs and has serval options to specify the structure and customize animations.

Everthing else is only css styling (Buttons etc.)

Comment: The .each() Method is just a plain loop or iterator. You should read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ You'll find examples and many explanations ;)